# WinRT What can be instead AncestorType?

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml

I want to get the count of a ListView items.
But it uses a Template, therefore, I need to use AncestorType, I have a code that in WPF works fine, but in Windows Store Apps 8 not, because there is no AncestorType there, so what can I do instead? How can I make this code works in winRT?

Here is my code:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Users}">
    <ListView.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ListView">
        <Style.Setters>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="LightGray">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <ScrollViewer>
                                    <ItemsPresenter />
                                </ScrollViewer>
                                <TextBlock Margin="0,4" FontWeight="Bold">
                                    <Run Text="Count: "/>
                                    <Run Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}, Path=Items.Count, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                </TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>                    
        </Style.Setters>
    </Style>
    </ListView.Style>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ListViewItem IsHitTestVisible="False">
                <StackPanel>
                    <facebookControls:ProfilePicture Height="74" Width="74" ProfileId="{Binding FacebookId}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding UserName}" FontSize="18" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                </StackPanel>
            </ListViewItem>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: I shared a solution for RelativeSource AncestorType in UWP over at http://stackoverflow.com/a/43399114/303612

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are in a `ControlTemplate`, you need some way to break out and address the underlying `DataContext`. It depends on how you defined the object you are binding to. For example, if you defined a `ViewModel` in the resources, you could access it the same as the `Users` property:

```xml
<UserControl ... >
  <UserControl.Resources>
      <vm:MyViewModel x:Key="ViewModel" />
  </UserControl.Resources>
  ...
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModel}}">
      <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Users}">
      ...
        <ControlTemplate>
        ...
          <Run Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModel},
                              Path=Users.Count}"/>
```

This is one way to deal with that.

Comment: I am in a ControlTemplate, that's why I wanted the AncestorType, can you advise what I can do instead?

Comment: Thanks, just needed to change the Path to Users.Count (no need for the Source)...

Answer (score 8):

The answer which was posted by Ed Chapel has one big disadvantage:

```
<vm:MyViewModel x:Key="ViewModel" />
```

leads to that `MyViewModel` will be constructed one more time. In common scenarios, this is unwanted behavior.

By the way, there is a perfect trick to bind to parent's `DataContext` without reconstructing a view-model.

Assuming `MyViewModel` has an 'ICommand' named TestCommand and is current `DataContext` of a page, which contains your `UserControl`, set the `x:Name` of a page and just bind `DataContext` of a page to a `Tag` property of `UserControl` using `ElementName` binding:

```
<Page...
    x:Name="rootPage">

    <Grid>
        <controls:MyUserControl Tag={Binding DataContext, ElementName='rootPage'} ... />
    </Grid>

    ...
</Page>
```

And then in XAML of your `UserControl` set the `x:Name` to `UserControl` and bind your property to a property in `Tag`:

```
<UserControl ...
    x:Name="rootControl">

    <Grid>
        <Button Command={Binding Tag.TestCommand, ElementName='rootControl'} ... />
    </Grid>

</UserControl>
```

That's, possibly, not the cleanest trick, which works because `Tag` property is a dependency property of type `object` and you can bind anything to it.

Answer (score 5):

Simplest solution is to name any root container which has your view model in Context and just set the DataContext of your control/container inside the ContentControl by mentioning element name, and you will get same context.

Example, (I have named my root grid of page as 'rootGrid' and set the context by *DataContext="{Binding ElementName=rootGrid, Path=DataContext}"* )

```
<ContentControl Name="contentControl" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                        >
        <Grid Height="600" 
              Width="600"
                 DataContext="{Binding ElementName=rootGrid, Path=DataContext}"
              > 

            <Image Height="500" Width="500" 

                   Source="{Binding photoUrl}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        </Grid>
    </ContentControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it like this in UWP

```
<GridView x:Name="abc" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.Companies,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"></GridView>
```