# UWP equivalent function to FindAncestor in uwp

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

I have a list of orders and when the order status is *Cancelled*, I want to blink the text. So far, my code works. However, **sometimes** it will throws exception:

> WinRT information: Cannot resolve TargetName lblOrderStatus

For some reason **lblOrderStatus** can be found. So, I want to use "FindAncestor", but FindAncestor doesn't exists in UWP. *Is there any equivalent function to FindAncestor in uwp?*

Here is my code:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="Orders" Grid.Row="1" Background="Transparent">
    ...
    ...
    ...
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                ...
                ...
                ...
                <Viewbox Grid.Column="3" StretchDirection="DownOnly" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="lblOrderStatus" Text="{Binding Path=OrderItemStatus, Mode=OneWay}" FontSize="18">
                        <TextBlock.Resources>
                            <Storyboard x:Name="sbBlinking">
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Opacity)"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetName="lblOrderStatus"
                                                 From="1" To="0" AutoReverse="True" Duration="0:0:0.5" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </TextBlock.Resources>
                        <interactive:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            <core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding OrderItemStatus, Converter={StaticResource EnumToStringConverter}}" ComparisonCondition="Equal" Value="Cancelled">
                                <media:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource sbBlinking}" />
                            </core:DataTriggerBehavior>
                        </interactive:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    </TextBlock>
                </Viewbox>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 17):

Considering all the solutions I've seen, I feel that using `ElementName` binding is the simplest workaround to UWP not having a RelativeSource AncestorType binding option.

Assuming you've got a `Page` with its `DataContext` set to a viewmodel with a command `MyCommand`, and you want each item in your list to execute it when its button is clicked:

```
<Page Name="thisPage">
    ...
    <ListView ...>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Command="{Binding ElementName=thisPage, Path=DataContext.MyCommand}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Page>
```

My initial problem with this solution is that you can't extract the DataTemplate out as a resource to use it on multiple screens (or even dialog boxes); `thisPage` might not exist in each of those places, or it might not be appropriate to name the root element "thisPage".

But if you use a convention where you include a token UI element in every screen that uses that DataTemplate, and refer to it by a consistent name, it will work. By default this element's DataContext will be your ViewModel (assuming your root element does too)

```
<Rectangle Name="VmDcHelper" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
```

...then in your standalone resources XAML file you can write your DataTemplate like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyDataTemplate">
    <Button Command="{Binding ElementName=VmDcHelper, Path=DataContext.MyCommand}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Then, on every page/screen/dialog that you use that template resource, just drop in a copy of that Rectangle (or whatever) and everything will bind correctly at run-time

This is clearly a hack solution, but after thinking about it some more, it doesn't feel like any more of a hack than using WPF's AncestorType in the first place (having to ensure that your ancestor type is always consistent in all the places you use your DataTemplate).

Answer (score 2):

I'm converting an app from WPF to UWP and found this thread. It seems there are no good solutions on the web, so here is my attempt to 'solve' this problem via workaround.

***NOTE:*** The following is **UNTESTED** in UWP (but works in WPF) as I'm part way through a large non-compiling port, but theoretically it should work...

## 1 Create a RelativeSourceBinding Attached Property

This class has two properties: AncestorType and Ancestor. When the AncestorType changes, we subscribe to FrameworkElement.Loaded (to handle parent changes) and find the visual parent of type and assign to the Ancestor attached property.

```
public class RelativeSourceBinding
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AncestorTypeProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("AncestorType", typeof(Type), typeof(RelativeSourceBinding), new PropertyMetadata(default(Type), OnAncestorTypeChanged));

    public static void SetAncestorType(DependencyObject element, Type value)
    {
        element.SetValue(AncestorTypeProperty, value);
    }

    public static Type GetAncestorType(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return (Type)element.GetValue(AncestorTypeProperty);
    }

    private static void OnAncestorTypeChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((FrameworkElement)d).Loaded -= OnFrameworkElementLoaded;

        if (e.NewValue != null)
        {
            ((FrameworkElement)d).Loaded += OnFrameworkElementLoaded;
            OnFrameworkElementLoaded((FrameworkElement) d, null);
        }
    }

    private static void OnFrameworkElementLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var ancestorType = GetAncestorType((FrameworkElement) sender);
        if (ancestorType != null)
        {
            var findAncestor = ((FrameworkElement) sender).FindVisualParent(ancestorType);
            RelativeSourceBinding.SetAncestor(((FrameworkElement)sender), findAncestor);
        }
        else
        {
            RelativeSourceBinding.SetAncestor(((FrameworkElement)sender), null);
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty AncestorProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Ancestor", typeof(UIElement), typeof(RelativeSourceBinding), new PropertyMetadata(default(FrameworkElement)));

    public static void SetAncestor(DependencyObject element, UIElement value)
    {
        element.SetValue(AncestorProperty, value);
    }

    public static UIElement GetAncestor(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return (UIElement)element.GetValue(AncestorProperty);
    }
}
```

Where FindVisualParent is an extension method defined as

```
public static UIElement FindVisualParent(this UIElement element, Type type) 
{
    UIElement parent = element;
    while (parent != null)
    {
        if (type.IsAssignableFrom(parent.GetType()))
        {
            return parent;
        }
        parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent) as UIElement;
    }
    return null;
}
```

## 2 Apply the RelativeSourceBinding property in XAML

some BEFORE xaml in WPF would look like this

```
<Style x:Key="SomeStyle" TargetType="local:AClass">
    <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="SomeProperty" Value="{Binding Foo, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:AnotherClass}}" />
    </Style.Setters>
</Style>
```

and AFTER xaml

```
<Style x:Key="SomeStyle" TargetType="local:AClass">
    <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="apc:RelativeSourceBinding.AncestorType" Value="local:AnotherClass"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding Path=(apc:RelativeSourceBinding.Ancestor).Foo, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
    </Style.Setters>
</Style>
```

It's a bit messy but in the case where you only have one RelativeSource FindAncestor type to find, it should work.

Comment: Hi, I'll test this out and report back. I haven't got a chance to look into it. Thanks again!

Comment: It does work. And if you need to, you can always rename the DPs to `Ancestor1Type` and `Ancestor1` and then implement `Ancestor2Type`, `Ancestor2`, and so on. As noted, the syntax isn't ideal, but it serves a need.

Comment: If you like it put a +1 ring on it :D

Comment: We have a helper for this in the Windows Community Toolkit here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/extensions/frameworkelementextensions#ancestortype

Answer (score 0):

**In XAML**
You can try using RelativeSource, it provides a means to specify the source of a binding in terms of a relative relationship in the run-time object graph.
For example using `TemplatedParent`:

```
Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, 
          Path=Parent.ActualHeight}
```

or

```
<Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" ></Binding>
```

In code you try using the VisualTreeHelper.GetParent method.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.visualtreehelper.getparent

something like the following, here is an example of a utility function

```
internal static void FindChildren<T>(List<T> results, DependencyObject startNode)
  where T : DependencyObject
{
    int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(startNode);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        DependencyObject current = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(startNode, i);
        if ((current.GetType()).Equals(typeof(T)) || (current.GetType().GetTypeInfo().IsSubclassOf(typeof(T))))
        {
            T asType = (T)current;
            results.Add(asType);
        }
        FindChildren<T>(results, current);
    }
}
```

The following example shows code that checks for an element's parent

```
((StackPanel)LinePane.Parent).ActualWidth;
```

Also, here is a good blog post showing this class in action. http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/09/how-to-access-named-control-inside-xaml.html

Comment: Hi Rami, how to apply VisualTreeHelper.GetParent in xaml? Sorry, I am new to UWP.

Comment: The purpose of the VisualTreeHelper class is to help with discovery of objects that you are looking for in the runtime tree of objects, but there isn't a more direct object-relationship API available for your scenario. Sometimes, you won't know the exact type or name of the object. Or perhaps you know that a specific object appears somewhere in the tree but you don't know the exact position. For these types of scenarios, VisualTreeHelper is helpful because you can recursively find all the objects in the visual tree and then look through this set and look for a match based on your criteria.

Comment: @Sam hope the above was helpful.

Comment: Hi Rami, if I use the c# code (not XAML); I just can't find a good way to do it (ie. bind OrderItemStatus and invoke Storyboard for that particular TextBlock). As you see, the items are in the list and when one of the item status changed to Cancelled, then I want it blink only for that specific item (not all items, but only for that specific item). I want to use VisualTreeHelper.GetParent, but just don't know how.

Comment: Hi @Sam, in this post there is an example of how to use GetChild(), which explains the same for GetParent() http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/09/how-to-access-named-control-inside-xaml.html

Comment: Hi Rami, yes, I did my research and now I know how to use GetParent, But my problem is that I do not know how to easily invoke/raise the particular storyboard when the status changed. The only way I can think of is to LOOP through all of those items in the list, find the DataContext, then find the Storyboard, then set the Storyboard target to its parent, then run/play the Storyboard. It is really ugly. I prefer the way to do it in XAML. I am half way through it. But it crashed every now and then.

Comment: So my question is, what is the replacement of FindAncestor in XAML. From what I have researched, there are none :(

Comment: @Sam, I just added another example to my answer. ((StackPanel)LinePane.Parent).ActualWidth; maybe this might help. as when to invoke? you should invoke based on the event you want the changes to happen (ie, status changed)

Comment: Hi @Sam, if you don't mind.  if the above was helpful. may you mark it as an answer so others will be able to see it as an answer? thanks

Comment: Hi Rami, back to my original question, I need to set this in XAML. If you look at what I am trying to achieve, it is too messy to be done in c# code. I'll mark this as answer if you know how to do FindAncestor equivalent in XAML (only in XAML). Otherwise, I'll wait for others to answer. Thanks mate...

Comment: @Sam did you try, RelativeSource in XAML? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/relativesource-markup-extension?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: yes, that is the first thing I tried, but it doesn't work :( :( :(