# TemplateBinding inside DataTemplate not working

Tags: .net, xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal

I'm creating a **Templated Control** in my Universal Windows Application.

The problem is that in the `<Button Content="{Binding}" Command="{TemplateBinding AddCharCommand}" />` the `TemplateBinding` doesn't work.

It seems that the problem is because it's defined inside a `DataTemplate`.

This is the `Style` and the template applied to my control.

```
<Style TargetType="local:CoordinatesControl">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:CoordinatesControl">

                <ListView ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding Numbers}">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Content="{Binding}"
                                    Command="{TemplateBinding AddCharCommand}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: It seems we can not use the `TemplateBinding` in the `DataTemplate`. We should be able to add the command in the `Number` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `TemplateBinding` inside `DataTemplate`, but there are workarounds:

1. You can create kind of proxy to some hidden element with `DataContext` you need. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47611214/3179044).
2. You can create kind of `RelativeSource` binding to find `Ancestor` like in [WPF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/relativesource-markupextension). More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43399114/3179044)

Comment: wow the second solution is a shitshow for such a common use case...